# Getting Year, Month and Date in Android

Tags: android, calendar

I am trying to get today's Year, Month and Date using following code;

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

int thisYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
Log.d(TAG, "# thisYear : " + thisYear);

int thisMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
Log.d(TAG, "@ thisMonth : " + thisMonth);

int thisDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
Log.d(TAG, "$ thisDay : " + thisDay);
```

But it gives "2012 for year 1 for month and 28 for date" which is not today's date. What I have done wrong?

Answer (score 23):

Would I be correct in assuming this is running on a Emulator? If so, Set the emulator date correctly, and it should be correct.

From memory, that code should do what you expect.

Comment: Thanks, I have set the date. But still month value is one below. It shows "8" but should be "9". Why is that?

Comment: @ErangaPeris Because it is zero based. Means 0 is for the first month.

Comment: also DAY_OF_MONTH return the number of day in month, use calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);

Answer (score 18):

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import android.widget.Toast;

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());

int currentYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int currentMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int currentDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

Toast.makeText(this,"Today's Date: " + currentYear + currentMonth + currentDay, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

"TimeZone" will work great if your application targets for Android API 27 platform or above

Answer (score 16):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
```

Comment: I happened to have used Calendar calendar = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().getCalendar(); that gave me wrong results. But yours work perfectly.

Comment: Please add 1 to the Result.

Comment: Just calling `Calendar.getInstance()` makes the same thing

Answer (score 8):

The month starts from zero so you have to add 1 with the given month to show the month number we are familiar with.

```
int thisMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
Log.d(TAG, "@ thisMonth : " + (thisMonth+1));
```

This will show you the current month starting with 1.

Answer (score 3):

try this one..

```
 Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
 currentMonth = instance.get(Calendar.MONTH);
 currentYear = instance.get(Calendar.YEAR);

 int month=currentMonth+1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and it is giving correct output.  You should try checking *time in your emulator/phone on which you are trying this code*.

According to getInstance docs, it sets to current date and time by Default.

Comment: Yes, I am running it with an emulator, created by Google API level 10. I tried to adjust the date of the emulator as follow. Menu -> Settings -> Date & Time There I have unchecked the "Automatic" option and set the date. Now the month is one number below than what I expect.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

```
Date dt = new Date(); 
dt.getYear(); 
dt.getMonth(); 
dt.getDay();
```

and see if you get the same result.
If so, your system date is probably out of sync.
Check [the Date class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) for more details:

Comment: These methods are deprecated in API level 1, use Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900 to get the current year

Answer (score 1):

This gives the time and date of your android system so first check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Initialising as `@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") final SimpleDateFormat dateAndTime = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MM-yy", Locale.getDefault());`

and `String timeStamp = dateAndTime.format(new Date());`