# Get month and year from system

Tags: android, string, date, calendar

can someone explain to me, how I get the month and year from Android. For example I need a "m" from "march" and the complete year.
I don't need it in one single String, their can be two strings for each.
I need them to replace html content with these strings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Year, Month and Date in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233803/getting-year-month-and-date-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the input data you have. For formatting, you can use the `SimpleDateFormat` class. If you need to replace the content with the current month/year, you can use the `currentTimeMillis` method.

```
long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

If the date you want to insert into the HTML is not the current date, but you do have a String containing the date, you can convert it to a Date object as demonstrated [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/).

If you want the month and year formatted like "April 2016", you can use the format "MMMM yyyy" like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy"); 
String dateString = dateFormat.format(date);
```

The rest of the formatting patterns can be found on many places, including [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

If you only want the first letter of the month, you could consider splitting the string on the space by using

```
String[] splitted = dateString.split("\\s+");
```

and grabbing the first character by using either

```
String monthChar = splitted[0].substring(0, 1);
```

or

```
char monthChar = splitted[0].charAt(0);
```

depending on the datatype you need.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do following to get Year and Month and Date in separate Strings:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```